# Magento 2 - Add a Custom Social Plugin to header.phtml

Tags: magento2

```
How to add a custom Social Login to header.phtml and to be displayed on the frontend?
```

[image]

I need to add custom social plugin before the Sign In?
   Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your template through xml,

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Module/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body> 
        <referenceBlock name= "header.panel">
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
                name="your.name"
                template="Magento_Theme::your_template.phtml">
             </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: cant get your answer. I was created in default.xml but its not working.